# Why the use of const in a method with no parameters?

Tags: c++, methods, constants

why is the purpose of "const" in that case?

```
std::string List::reqClubName() const
{
    return m_Club;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly, the method I am using does not use any parameters ()

Comment: So const in my case is to make sure the method does not modify anything. Am I right?

Comment: @user2984887 indeed. They can't change any members of the variable, unless they were declared mutable.

Answer (score 4):

Banning the modification of members is not the only reason to qualify a member function as `const`. Whether you want to modify members or not, you can *only* call a member function on an object through a `const` context if the member function is marked `const`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct List
{
   std::string reqClubName()
   {
      return m_Club;
   }

private:
   std::string m_Club;
};

int main()
{
   const List l;
   std::cout << l.reqClubName();
   // ^ illegal: `l` is `const` but, `List::reqClubName` is not
}
```

Neither the language nor the compiler care that `reqClubName` doesn't try to modify the object anyway; your program will not compile.

Because of this, a `const` suffix should be your default approach unless you *do* need to modify a data member.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` after a member function says that the function does not modify member data in the class it is a part of.

Comment: While correct, this does not answer the question really.